# HTML button formaction not scrolling down to a particular region in the other html page

Tags: html, css

I have a button which I have made with the following code:

```
<form>
<button class="Button1" type="submit" formaction="Button1.html#Part2">Go to part2
</button>
</form>
```

Now in my Button1.html, I have made a part2 as follows:

```
<p id=”Part2”>Here is your part 2</p>
```

Now when I click the button1, it takes me to Button1.html and the url is displayed on top as `file:///D:/yourDir/Button1.html#Part2`

but it doesn't scrool down to the part 2 which is pretty below in the Button1.html

Please guide me about this issue

Comment: What are you using to scroll the page? You need JavaScript or jQuery to refocus the window somehow. Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586594/scroll-up-and-down-a-div-on-button-click-using-jquery) covering a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchors are created by something like:

```
<a name="anchorname">Guide me!</a>
```

So in your case it has to be:

```
<a name="Part2">Here is your part 2</a>
```

You also can try this:

```
<a name="Part2"></a><p id="Part2">Here is your part 2</p>
```

If you need the id for the p-element. But leaving the a-tag empty can cause issues, so maybe it's not scrolling exactly to `Here is your part 2`

Answer (score 1):

You need to add some javascript to your html page, this will work if you use a link to make buttons:

```
<a href="#section1" class="scroll">Button 1</a>
<a href="#section2" class="scroll">Button 2</a>
```

and add this JS script to your page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[class="scroll"]').click(function(){
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $( $.attr(this, 'href') ).offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
    }); 
});
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/56kommunikation/5nroor80/

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: I was looking for a pure html based solution, anyway thumbs up for a valuable response!

Comment: Thank you. Just to be clear, this works also without js but with no 'soft scrolling'. Cheers