# How to make a scroll button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I would like to keep the overflow hidden and instead put a div on the page to where you can hover over it and it will scroll down. I can not seem to figure out how this would be accomplished. I have searched the web and haven't had any luck. I have an idea that this may need some jquery but I am not positive.

Comment: Do you mean that you want a div to have a specific height initially and upon hovering over a button to increase the height of the div and display the rest of the content of the div? Can you provide us a live example of what you want to accomplish or your code?

Comment: Hi, May be you could do it with only html and css. Please see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/K6zCT/1441/

Comment: No, it is not an expanding div. I have a div container that has content in it. I have enough content to where it is starting to get hidden because the overflow is hidden so what i would like is a button to hover over and scroll down the div container.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586594/scroll-up-and-down-a-div-on-button-click-using-jquery

Comment: By "scroll down" do you mean the height should be increased?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that this is your HTML:

```
<div id="button">Scroll down</div>
<div id="container">
    <p>Your text or content here.</p>
</div>
```

Basically, you need to use the jQuery hover function for the button and then the animate for the container:

```
$('#button').hover(function(){
    $('#container').animate({scrollTop: $('#container')[0].scrollHeight}, 2500);
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8o4y9y/1/)

---

You can accomplish this using absolute positioning and jQuery's `.animate()` and `.stop()` method.

To make the div scroll up:

```
$("div.content").stop().animate({top: "-400%"}, 5000); 
//Let's say the div is 500% tall
```

To make the div stop moving:

```
$("div.content").stop();
```

To make the div scroll down:

```
$("div.content").stop().animate({top: "0"}, 5000);
```

---

Of course, the only problem with this is that it doesn't prorate the time it takes to scroll, so if you start from only 50% from the bottom and you try to scroll to the bottom, it will still take 5 seconds even though scrolling from the top takes 5 seconds.

You could probably fix this by using the value for `top` and dividing it by `(height() - 100%).

---

### [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ey8o4y9y/1/)