# Targeting objects in storyline with javascript

Tags: javascript, triggers, articulate-storyline

I cannot select a scrolling panel as an object for a trigger. I'm trying to have a scrolling panel move when a button is clicked. And return to its previous position when it loses focus.

I'd like to do so via motion paths or JavaScript for UX purposes. I know it can be done with an entrance animation and the use of a show layer trigger, but that solution lacks the return animation.

I have experience with JavaScript and can accomplish the animation with code but do not know how to target the object directly (ie. by name).

After posting on the Articulate community forums:
https://community.articulate.com/discussions/articulate-storyline/using-triggers-to-move-a-scrolling-panel-in-storyline-2#reply-230801

**It seems the only way to accomplish this would be via javascript.**

Per the staff's reply. Does anyone know how I could target the object directly? If I can I'll just animate with jQuery and easing.

Comment: It sounds like you have a HTML element, possibly a div with scroll bar, and want to move the scroll bar position via a button press (disregard the blur portion for now).  Is that correct?  If so, this thread might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586594/scroll-up-and-down-a-div-on-button-click-using-jquery

Comment: You can find the element via inspection with browser tools.