# Scrolling down with button

Tags: javascript, html

Given the following button :

```
  <section id="section04" class="demo">
  <h1>Scroll Down Button #4</h1>
  <a><span></span>Scroll</a>
  </section>
```

How can I make the button scroll down on the page with a particular amount?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [scroll up and down a div on button click using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16586594/scroll-up-and-down-a-div-on-button-click-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery animate

```
$("#section04").click(function(){
  $("html, body").stop().animate({
    scrollTop: 100px
  },1000);
});
```

Change 100px to any value required.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use vanilla javascript you can use windows built in methods scrollTo

```
//.html

   <div style='height:4000px; border:solid red 2px; width:80%;'>
      <input type='text' class='y' />
      <button>Scroll Y-axis</button>
   </div>

//.js

    var button = document.querySelector('button')

    button.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var y = document.querySelector('.y').value
            window.scrollTo(0,y)
    })
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kornholio/7pw1ag77/1/)